# How to Prevent UI Freeze?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My View

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload",
            new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",
                OnBegin = "showModal", //Modal to display UploadPercentage
                OnSuccess = "uploadCompleted", //Modal to display UploadCompleted
                OnFailure = "uploadFailed", //Modal to display UploadFailed
            }))
//Submit button
```

My UploadController

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Upload(Model model)
{
    bool completed = UploadProcess();
    if(completed)
        return HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    else
        return HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

public bool UploadProcess()
{
    tcp.send(uploadmsg); // send msg to start uploadprocess btwn client and host
    while(uploadpercentage != 100)
    {
        result = receive(out msg); // receive msg from TcpHost
    }
    return true; // return true after upload completed
}

public bool Receive(out string msg)
{
    // Scan tcp received msg
    // Another void function to push uploadpercentage to UI using signalR
}
```

Hi guys, not sure if I am doing it correctly. Based on my understanding, AJAX depends on HttpStatusCode to decide whether it is a Success or Failure. It works well. What I am doing here is I have a User to send a msg via browser to inform Client Machine A to upload file to Host Machine via TCP Connection. At the same time, Host Machine will send TCP Msg about the UploadingInformation to WebServer.

I am able to scan the upload percentage and show it to Web User via SignalR. But while browser is uploading/listening for TCP_UploadMsg, the user UI will be frozen and couldn't do anything on the new tab too. It doesn't happen on another Session browser.

Can anyone suggest me what to do to prevent UI freeze? Will BackgroundWorker able to solve my problem?

Comment: Background worker will be able to solve the problem. You can also google .. async and await

Comment: hi, @MohitShrivastava, can you give me some hints on how should I implement the backgroundworker based on my case?

Answer (score 0):

The smallest code for UI to get updated while process works on another thread will be

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    result = receive(out msg);
}));
```

### **EDIT**

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnBegin = "showModal", //Modal to display UploadPercentage
            OnSuccess = "uploadCompleted", //Modal to display UploadCompleted
            OnFailure = "uploadFailed", //Modal to display UploadFailed
        }))    
}));
```

Comment: I still unable to browse another page on the same site while the uploading is processing. The problem is due to ActionResult Upload is not finished. How do I run the Ajax without UI Freezing?

I tried implementing your code. But the closest I get in C# MVC is 


    `while (uploadpercentage != 100)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
             result = Receive(out msg);
        }));
    }`

Comment: Edited it PLease try that and see it works... I am pretty sure it will work. else you can also try `this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
 bool completed = UploadProcess(); 
}));
`

Comment: this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { bool completed = UploadProcess(); })); is not working. My new tab which has the same session that initiate the uploadProcess is loading for the page until the uploadProcess is finished.